# Proving that a set is dedekind-infinite if and only if it has a countably infinite subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am interested in proving the following statement:

> A set is Dedekind-infinite if and only if it has a countably infinite subset.

Here is my attempt:

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $A$ has a countably infinite subset $E$. Arrange the terms of $E$ in a sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots$ of distinct elements. Now let $f:A\to A\setminus\{x_0\}$ be defined as follows:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1} &\text{if $x=x_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$} \\
x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to a proper subset of $A$, namely $A\setminus\{x_0\}$.

However, I am unsure how to prove the forward implication. Does it require a form of the axiom of choice?

Comment: I'm not sure what the bounty is for. Arvid gave a complete answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is in bijection with a proper subset $B$, that is, there exists a bijection $f : A \to B$. Suppose $x_0 \in A-B$. Then we can define a sequence of distinct terms by $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, which is countably infinite as $f$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand this answer now. If we let $B$ be a proper of subset of $A$ for which there is a bijection $f:A\to B$, then we define an injective map $\phi:\mathbb N\to B$ given by $\phi(n)=f^n(x_0)$. Then, $\phi(\mathbb N)\subseteq B\subsetneq A$, and $|\phi(\mathbb N)|=|\mathbb N|$, so $\phi(\mathbb N)$ is a countably infinite subset of $A$.

Comment: Right. And you need to prove that the map $\mathbb{N} \to B$ is injective. To this end: Suppose for contradiction that $f^k(x_0) = f^{k+n}(x_0)$ for some $k$, $n>0$. Using injectivity of $f$, we get $x_0 = f^n(x_0)$. But we choose $x_0 \not\in f(A)$, a contradiction.